How to ASP.NET Web API webrtc Server create
I am working on a project where I need to establish a WebRTC server using ASP.NET Web API. My goal is to facilitate real-time communication between users, allowing them to connect directly to each other.
I have a basic understanding of WebRTC, including concepts such as SDP (Session Description Protocol), ICE candidates, and the roles of STUN/TURN servers. However, I am having difficulty finding comprehensive documentation or examples on how to implement the signaling server part using ASP.NET Web API.
Here's what I am specifically looking to achieve:

Create an API endpoint to handle SDP offers and answers.

Create an API endpoint to handle ICE candidate exchanges.

Use STUN/TURN servers to help peers discover their public IP addresses and port numbers.

Maintain a list of active connections and manage peer-to-peer connections efficiently.


Could someone provide a detailed guide or example code on how to set up these API endpoints in ASP.NET Web API? Any additional tips on integrating STUN/TURN server configurations would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
